# Intersection of Symmetric Convex Sets

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons, convex-geometry

Given a symmetric convex compact set $K\in\mathbb{R}^2$, show there are no sequences $(r_i)_{i=1}^n$ of positive scalars and $(P_i)_{i=1}^n$ of points in $\partial K$, so that $n>1$ and

$$\sum_{i=1}^n r_iP_i\in \mathrm{interior}\bigcap_{i=1}^n r_i(K+P_i)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

In other words, given a collection of scaled (not rotated) copies of $K$, each containing the origin in its boundary, is it not possible for the sum of all the centers of the copies to be contained in the interior of the intersection?

### Progress:

I think this works.

First, note that the easiest case should be when we shrink the RHS of (*) to $K=\mathrm{symm.conv}\{P_i\}$

So for $n=2$, start with $K$ a parallelogram $ADBC$ and pick $P_1=A,\ \ \  P_2=C,\ \ \  r_1=r_2=1$. [image] Since $C\in\partial K$, we have $A+C\in\partial(K+A)$ and similarly $A+C\in\partial (K+C)$. Then, $A+C\in\partial((K+A)\cap(K+C))$ since the intersection of boundaries is contained in the boundary of the intersection. We didn't actually use anything about parallelograms - this argument generalizes to any symmetric convex $K$ with $r_1=r_2$.

On to $r_1\neq r_2$. Working under $r_1>r_2$ and fixing $r_1+r_2=2$, the point $r_1A+r_2C$ travels along the segment from $A+C$ to $A^\prime$. That means it separates from $K+C$, which contains $r_2K+C$. So, $A+C\not\in r_1(K+A)\cap r_2(K+C)$. This also generalizes to any symmetric convex $K$.

I think next is reducing $n=3$ and so on to $n=2$. Not attacking symmetric hexagons and points roaming in triangles.

We might divide through by $\sum r_i$ to assume WLOG $\sum r_i=1$. Then, $\sum r_iP_i$ ranges over the interior $K$. However, that introduces a dependence among the $r_i$.